# Querying into alternate workspaces with Rally C# API

Tags: rally

I'm making a bunch of Rally API calls using the C# Rally Rest API Wrapper, with great success... except when I'm trying to query into a non-default workspace. For example, take this code:

```
public Project GetProject(string objectID)
    {
        Request request = new Request("Project");
       // request.Workspace = "2354109555"; //"CTO:SST";
        request.Query = new Query("ObjectID", Query.Operator.Equals, objectID);
        QueryResult q = _restApi.Query(request);
        foreach (var result in q.Results)
        {
            return CreateProjectFromResult(result);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

If objectID is in the default workspace, the project is found. If it is not, it is not found. I've tried setting the Workspace property to the workspace object id, the workspace name, not setting it.. to no avail. I've also gone into Rally, switched my default workspace, and verified the switch in which projects are successfully obtained.

I've also triple checked the objectIDs for the projects and workspaces.

I'm officially stumped. Does anyone have the magic answer or something else I can try?

Much appreciated,
Orlando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're 99 pct of the way there. When you specify a workspace attribute on your Request object, it needs to be in the form of a ref, i.e.:

```
  request.Workspace = "/workspace/2354109555"; //"CTO:SST";
```

Your code should pull from that Workspace once you make that modification.

Comment: Thanks! I verified this worked.. I don't think I would have bridged that last 1%.

Comment: You'll find a similar pattern for other parameters, i.e. userRef = "/user/12345678910"; storyRef = "/hierarchicalrequirement/12345678911"; projectRef = "/project/12345678912"; etc, etc.